# Killed wrong session and cannot connect to oracle anymore

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I guess I killed the wrong session. Trying to connect with SQL Developer, it says `ORA-12505`.

Search results say you may set wrong SID, but that's not for my case.

How can I get my oracle back?

My web service is also down with same error.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/net12500.htm  Have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Comment: okay.. I'm trying to find oracle root to restart. `/oracle/10.2.0/db/dbs/init.ora` and `/oracle/10.2.0/db/srvm/admin/init.ora`. Now I wonder which is right

Comment: For SQL Developer. Try disconnecting and then reconnect

Comment: If you're unable to connect to Oracle because a critical process has been killed you may have to reboot your computer. Best of luck.